# Create shortcuts for commands in windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

Its a general question, but I think that with my cenario is easy to explain. My deal is the following:

I have some files, I want to move them to a new folder that I am about to create, usually I press `ctrl`+`shift`+`n` to create a new folder, then I go to the files, select them and press to `ctrl`+`x` to cut, then go to inside the folder and paste.

I would like to do something like that:
Select the files, press some combination of keys, some that doesn't exist, and it creates the folder, let me give the name, and after I press `Enter` it moves the files to the folder autoatically.

Keep in mind that this should be something general, something I can write to a script or anything and use for multiple cenarios.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. (And the fact you're *selecting some files* means you're not using the command line, so the *command-line* and *cmd* tags are inappropriate.) Also, as a suggestion: You'll find very few sites on [se] that will accept a *general question*; most want a **specific** question that asks about a clearly stated problem.

Comment: @KenWhite Actually, i can be a programming question, since it could be solved by some .bat file that is fired by some shortcut. And by general question I mean that can be used for others purposes, not only my question itself. But I got what you meant, I will look for some information there. Thanks

Comment: As written, this is not a programming question. If you have a programming question, ask about a programming solution, including the research you've done so far to figure this out yourself first. That research would also require an extensive search here for existing questions that may answer all or part of your question. Your question as written mentions nothing about programming, shows no research effort, and doesn't even ask a specific question. Please either move it to the site I suggested, or [edit] to show what you've done so far and what research you've done.